# Encouraging use of a new Facebook group

Tags: site-growth, facebook

I recently created a Facebook group, linked to an extant page, hoping to make it easy for all community members to participate. I've gotten a decent number of people to join the new group, and am getting ready to reach out to some to ask them to post directly.

Does anyone have some best practices to share to speed this new group along? Are there things that work better on Facebook, or that help build the community more quickly than the usual slog? (I'm not in a hurry, but if there are obvious things unique to Facebook about community-building, happy to incorporate them sooner.)

Answer (score 2):

You can arrange a raffle of bonuses. For example, "Place this post on your page and receive a bonus additional product features without payment". This may be another option.

Answer (score 1):

I have found two things that specifically help Facebook groups grow.

First is setting an example. I have found that once the community gets the idea of what content the group is for, they will start posting it. If the group name and description don't make this clear enough, examples can help - a lot. The usual seeding of posts to appear each day is one way. Another is to have a theme for each day of the week. When the community posts something give them a lot of love in the form of replies and comments.

Second is starting conversations (and stimulating). Nothing cements a community like a few interesting conversations. Posting daily questions - especially very open-ended questions can get the conversations going.

Either way, look at the stats for the group. Over time, a few members will stand out as top contributors. Build a relationship with these people. Some will be your future moderators, others will just be top contributors. Help them to have a sense of ownership in the group.

As a bonus idea, it can help to make a group look better engaged by finding older posts by other people and commenting on them (again). Not only does that cause the previous likers and commenters (and OP) to come back to it, but the post is returned to the top of the group.